# In what English-speaking communities does "trump" refer to the breaking of wind?

Tags: american-english, british-english, slang, offensive-language

It is clear from [this site](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/trump-fart.1529620/) that the verb *to trump* has been used extensively across Britain to refer to the breaking of wind. It is especially the case in the North, in Wales and certainly in Norfolk, when I was a child in the 1950s.

This use is confirmed by the OED. However though it is therein described as *vulgar* my own experience is that it was a term encouraged by parents as a means of avoiding the far less socially salubrious *fart*.

However its use appears to be unknown in the United States, which seems a pity! Is this definitely the case?

> b. To give forth a trumpet-like sound; spec. to break wind audibly
>   (slang or vulgar).

Comment: With the right context, I'm sure we AmEs could work out what you meant. But we certainly don't use *trump* to mean *fart* here.

Comment: @DanBron It is somewhat dated in Britain - but most people, I believe, would be aware of it. It has the clear association with the act of breaking wind, that I for one am glad that it is not my surname! (If ever there is a President Trump, it should prove a field day to British cartoonists.)

Comment: Believe me when I tell you if there's ever a President Trump, it will be a field day for American cartoonists as well.

Comment: @DanBron - It appears that the play on words has already started!  https://mobile.twitter.com/glinner/status/207620328967512064 / http://www.democraticunderground.com/discuss/duboard.php?az=view_all&address=439x891789

Comment: This has got to make bridge games really entertaining.

Comment: @JoeBlow That's right. You've got it exactly.

Comment: @DanBron Your comment was a lot funnier before the most recent U.S. presidential election.

Comment: @Carlton Lots of things were funnier before the election. Or, to paraphrase that classic trio, the Animaniacs, "Things were 'ha-ha' funny, and now they're more 'uh-oh' funny".

Comment: @DanBron Anyone entering politics with the surname "Windbag" would undoubtedly feel compelled to change it. In Britain,"Trump" is not far away from "Windbag", I feel I should point out.

Comment: @WS2 Well, we have a President Trump, but AFAIK no cartoonists or comedians on this side of the pond have made the link to this British slang. There's plenty of other stuff about him to ridicule. Do British school children have a laugh at his name?

Comment: @Barmar [Berke Breathed did](http://www.gocomics.com/bloom-county/2015/08/21), but he clearly marked it as British.

Answer (score 9):

It appears to be mainly a BrE slang expression:

[To trump](https://books.google.it/books?id=qn-DASgdhiAC&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=trump%20meaning%20fart&source=bl&ots=KdXJZyMOiM&sig=8bz2iWY2VuzTD7pW-MXIXSbHKYk&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBmoVChMIxbbox7iLxwIVhm8UCh0h4QnC#v=onepage&q=trump%20meaning%20fart&f=false):

> - Over the centuries, fart has not been without linguistic rivals. Since the early fifteenth century, for example, trump has served as a synonym for fart, or rather to denote an especially noisy fart.

(A Dictionary of Culinary Curiosities) 
 by Mark Morton

[Trump](http://www.peevish.co.uk/slang/t.htm):

> - Verb. To break wind from the anus, to 'fart'. E.g."There's a disgusting smell in here. Has someone trumped?"
> - Noun. 1. An act of breaking wind. 2)The resulting smell of having broke wind from the anus, a 'fart'.

(www.peevish.co.uk/slang)

Comment: As someone pointed out on the site whose link I gave in the question, some biblical quotations, when I was a child at school always brought forth a snigger - e.g. 1 Corinthians 15.52 - *the last trump shall sound*.

Answer (score 6):

Me and my 3 siblings all used "trump" as children instead of "fart". "Fart" was definitely considered to be the ruder of the two words, and my parents preferred that we said "trump". We don't use the word often now, as we're all adults and tend to say "fart" instead. We come from Warrington in North West England and mostly grew up in the '90s.

Answer (score 1):

In the U.S. there's a clearly related though gentler expression:  "to toot."  Mothers generally prefer children to say "toot" rather than "fart," as you can see on this [Circle of Moms Question and answer page](http://www.circleofmoms.com/welcome-circle-moms/what-should-children-call-farts-166211).  There's also a children's rhyme, which [you can read variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beans,_Beans,_the_Musical_Fruit) of on Wikipedia:

> Beans, beans, the magical fruit
>   The more you eat the more you toot,
>   The more you toot the better you feel,
>   So let's have beans with every meal!

Comment: Mean while in England we learned that "beans, beans, they're good for your heart - the more you eat the more you fart..." the rest of the rhyme was the same.

Comment: @glenatron I'm in the US and I remember your version as well. It probably depends on the age of the kids reciting it -- teens and preteens probably prefer the more vulgar version, while smaller children will go with the version their parents use.